# Setting Windows process permissions from shell or script

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd

I'm blessed with some processes on my machine that I can not kill by default - Task Manager claims "Access is denied". Since I have admin access, I *can* kill these processes in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) by modifying their permissions and granting "Full Control" to the Administrators group before attempting to kill them.

I'd like to automate this in a script, preferrably in standard CMD, if necessary using PowerShell or .NET scripting. Could anyone point me towards the necessary invocations?

Comment: `runas /user:Administrator taskkill /im processName* /f` .If you need to supply the administrator user with password you'll need cpau:http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/index.htm  .If you need to change the priority of the process try with wmic command: `wmic process where name="explorer.exe" call setpriority 64`

Comment: Thank you, taskkill does what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Added npocmaka's comment as an answer.*

Use the following statement to kill a process as Administrator:

```
runas /user:Administrator taskkill /im processName* /f
```